# How can I center the dots on a scatter chart in JavaFX 2.0?

Tags: javafx-2

When using the JavaFX 2.0 scatter chart the plotted dots are graphed with the top left corner of the dot touching the point rather than the center of the dot on the point. So rather than it looking like it is plotting at the point (1, 1) it looks more like it's at (1.1, 0.9). Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in a way ScatterChart draws shifting plotted dots.

Until fix as a workaround you can override dots style class. To perform that add new file "style.css" to the same package with your main class and next content:

```
.chart-symbol { /* solid circle */
    -fx-background-color: #f9d900;
    -fx-background-radius: 5px;
    -fx-translate-x: -4px;
    -fx-translate-y: -4px;
}
```

In the code where your main scene is created add next line:

```
scene.getStylesheets().add("style.css");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did as you said but I'm getting an error. I'll show you the little snippet of code that I have it in.

`mRoot = new Group();
Scene scene = new Scene(mRoot);
scene.getStylesheets().add("src/functionvuefx/desktop/style.css");
primaryStage.setScene(scene);`

The error I am getting says.
`WARNING: com.sun.javafx.css.StyleManager loadStylesheet Resource "null" not found.`

I've been trying to fix it, but am not having much luck.

Comment: StyleManager can't find css file by that path. Try next way (note leading slash and no src): `scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/functionvuefx/desktop/style.css").toExternalForm());`

Comment: Thank you so much. Both of you helped a bunch. I ended up just having to get rid of the src/ from the previous one. You really saved my project.

Comment: Both of me are very happy for you :)

Comment: Note, that this issue was fixed in 2.2: http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-18389